# How to import CSV file using WEBMATRIX3 environment?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix-3

How to import CSV file using WEBMATRIX3 environment?

I am working on a application using webmatrix3 which will suggest the items by name or category comes from CSV file, which must be import into database.

[PHP offers a very nice and clean way to do it exactly the way I want to do like](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/ajax-search-suggest-wearehunted/)

but how to do it using asp.net web pages (Razor syntax)? using Webmatrix environment?

Comment: The page you are linking to has not a single entry of the word "CSV". Is this whole question simply SPAM?

Comment: I did'nt said that attached link is showing CSV functionality.

Comment: I did'nt said that attached link is showing CSV functionality. i was just showing the results of that link which exactly matches the functionality which i want to perform using search box. but for that i am here to ask only that is there any way to import CSV file into webmatrix to perform this functionality??

Answer (score 0):

This page has several examples, I have used the file chooser example it works great: 
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/working-with-files

Once you have the file uploaded you can import the CSV like this:
[Webmatrix csv import to SQL Server Compact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594114/webmatrix-csv-import-to-sql-server-compact)

I hope that helps